# Unknown number of $.get requests; how to chain effectively?

Tags: jquery, promise, get

In a DB, I have an array of keys used to fetch data from other tables. The number of items in the array varies.

So, I can set up multiple variables on the fly:

```
var keys = ["3958d9d0kdjcu4","49djs40dksnhjd","fjfjfjtnncxkshe"]
for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    window.keys[i] = i;
}
```

But, how to chain an indeterminate number of $.get requests?:

```
var A = $.get("db.url?id=key0");
var B = $.get("db.url?id=key1");
var C = $.get("db.url?id=key2");
// etc.

$.when( A, B, C).done(function(A, B, C) {
//...
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this with an indeterminate number of requests, place the jqXHR objects returned from `$.get()` (or `$.ajax()`, or `$.post()`) in to an array, then apply that array to `$.when()`, like this:

```
var requests = [];
for (var i = 0; i < requestsToBeMade; i++) {
  requests.push($.get(`db.url?id=key${i}`));
}

$.when.apply($, requests).done(function() {
  // do some work here...
});
```

However, while this will work it's not ideal. You shouldn't be making multiple AJAX requests in quick succession like this, as it's putting an necessary load on the server, and will not scale.

A better solution would be to merge all the data you're sending and make a single request instead.

Comment: Thanks. It will only be between one and 4 requests, but I appreciate the approach & advice.